oauth example of bearer jwt token missing validation token belongs to user by not storing mapping on server side?
wrt https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/ dont we have to ensure token belongs to same user ?
I see code has login to generate token (authenticate_user).  on client side some where (localstorage in browser) it can be stored but then on server side its not mentioned where its stored.  I would expect that for each user or some entity it should be stored in cache/db.  so in create_user_token we need to store in db user:token mapping and in get_current_user we should also have some way to compare the token for user ? compare TokenData.username for request TokenData.username ?
so its left to user to implement it ? or am I misunderstanding and already implemented in example ?
regards,
miten.

A JWT contains the user id in the token. Since it's signed with a key only you have, and can verify that the signature is correct, you can trust that you previously verified that the user id is the real user id. If you used a randomly generated token, you'd store the user id server side and look it up from the random token (which is what a regular session does). But since a JWT is signed, the client can provide all the relevant information back to you (that they previously got from you or a third party) in a way you can trust.

You may use JWT token for validating user if you use verify signature flag when decoding the JWT token. However it is crucial not to store any secret information in the JWT payload, because it is easily accessible by the client. Also to note JWT doesn't check the user data against changes in your database. For example if you added user_id to the payload JWT doesn't check that the user wasn't deleted from the database on the server side.
Useful information about WJT:
JWT token is the string that has three parts {part1}.{part2}.{part3}. Here part2 contains the payload that you want to add to the JWT. This data is not secured anyhow and can be decoded and viewed by the user. Whilst part3 is an securely encoded signature key and hash of the payload. JWT library uses part3 to check that the JWT token was created by the server (using given signature key) and that the payload wasn't modified by a user.
